# Local deploy in vs2012 using web.config transforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Our shop is testing out Visual Studio 2012 so that we're ready to use it once it drops, and I've been tasked with running it through the paces to make sure everything will work as needed. So far I have only found one issue, and that is deploying our solution with our web.config transforms so that I can then transfer it to the servers for use in on our development network. We've set up different configs (release, staging, development) as needed and they all work in VS2010, but when I try to find the place to deploy the package as I normally do I can't find anywhere to do it in the IDE.

I've found a ton of articles online about publishing to a server or using FTP but in our environment that isn't possible, we have to build it on our machine and then transfer it sneakernet style (not ideal but required) to the servers ourselves. I can't seem to find how to do this though. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, what you are asking about deploying an application via FTP from VS2012 to your remote machine is it?

Comment: No, I just need to deploy a web app from vs2012 to a folder on my desktop so that I can then copy it to my wwwroot manually on a differnt machine in the office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be what you are looking for, but can't you right click on the root folder in solution explorer and select publish website? (I would have made this simply as a comment, but I don't have enough rep to do that.)

---

[image: What I see]

Comment: The publish website option isn't showing up. I looked for that (which is how we publish in 2010) but can't find the option anywhere.

Comment: It may be a power tools option? I'm not sure, I don't have a box w/o power tools to test on. Try installing power tools for 2012.

Comment: Ah, you have to build a publishing profile. You've indirectly answered it! Thank you!

EDIT: I can't upvote you yet :(